# table* not visible in article

Tags: tables, pdftex, miktex

I have run into a really weird issue. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{here}

\begin{document}

Test

\begin{table*}[H]
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    A & B\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

Test

\end{document}
```

The output document with pdfLaTeX has no table in it. There are no warnings and no errors. I tried multiple online editors as well, but without any luck - the table remains invisible and does not even consume any space. If I replace the `table*` environment by a `table` environment, it works fine.

Background: I used a `table*` like this one in a document that I update each year since at least 2014. Only this year it stopped working after an update of my local MikTeX setup. I cannot pinpoint the exact version, but it worked on multiple MikTeX installations across multiple machines in the past. I do not understand why it stopped working. I suspect that it might have to do with the `here` package.

Question: Is this a bug or - if not - why did it work previously and why am I not seeing any warnings or errors? Note: I'll happily use `table` instead of `table*` for now, but I want to avoid missing content/tables in my documents.

Comment: `[H]` can not be used with `table*` (what would it mean?)

Comment: I originally had double-column documents and thought that using `table*` in a single-column document would not make a difference. It did indeed make no difference in the last few years that I continued using `table*`s.

Comment: Sorry yes I didn't notice originally that it was a single column document, but given `H` can't work when `table*`  is being used for two column, it's not that surprising if it doesn't work in single column `table*`. I can't recall if it did in my original `here` package but that was withdrawn in the 1990's `here` has just been a wrapper that inputs the `float` package since that time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did not know that. I will look for a better solution if the package is no longer intended to be used. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried the supplied file with texlive2016,texlive2017,texlive2018,texlive2019  with same result in all.

Comment: `here.sty` is (in total) the line `\RequirePackage{float}`  that's all.